# 4 smartphone users position check

Tags: html, gps, geolocation, smartphone

Since many days, I'm trying to figure out how to set up a geocache website that would force 4 people to be at 4 different locations with each their smartphone and the localisation set on. Once they would be at the same time at these locations, they would get extra instructions (coordinates of the geocache, instructions for the next stage, ...)

It's not my purpose, but if necessary, the 4 users would first have to register (choose a team name and a pwd), then log in, then go at the same time a the 4 different locations, then they would get the information, ...

Is there somebody who could help me on the methodology or even beter that could help me coding this as a webpage ?

Thanks in advance

Esc78

Answer (score 0):

This page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation covers web geolocation in some detail.

The basics are:

Do they have geolocation:

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  /* geolocation is available */
} else {
  /* geolocation IS NOT available */
}
```

Where are they:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I got this. I'm able to check the position of a single user. But I don't have a clue how to check if the 4 users are at 4 given locations at the same time. As long as all 4 users are not at the 4 given different locations, the next set of information should not be given to the users

Comment: When the four users access your webpage you will have their locations. Keep track of them someplace.  If less than 4 they wait, when you have all four (and they are "far enough" apart) you can send them the 2nd part of the data.  You will need to decide what "far enough" is, because they will all have unique locations even if they are all standing hand-in-hand.  Useful formula: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any Idea how to store these 4 locations from a "hidden" way, without having to set up a server or at least store them on a server ?

Comment: You are definitely going to need a server.

Comment: This is what I was affraid of :-)